# Get current stream position on a timer

Tags: ios, google-cast

I am trying to update a UISlider to match the time of the currently Casting stream. Every second I call:

```
mediaControlChannel.mediaStatus.streamPosition
```

But it always returns whatever the last time I scrubbed to.

How can I find the current streamPosition from a Cast device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`approximateStreamPosition`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/interface_g_c_k_media_control_channel.html#a0108b52f99f28cfe6052e0486260add2) to get the current stream position; SDK manages that.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. Do you also know how can I get periodic updates of this value, instead of creating a timer and asking for it?

Comment: I don't think SDK provides any periodic update of that nature, which means you'd need to add your own timer.